# Rename Hyper-V VMs to include their S/N

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm trying to bulk-rename some Hyper-V VM's to include the first 4 digits of their BIOS serial number. I do this by pulling the VM names and the associated S/Ns, and then try to rename the VM's using this info, naming each VM using the associated S/N in the pulled table.

It pulls the necessary info fine, meaning the name of the VM's (elementname) and the S/N's (BIOSSerialNumber), however the renaming process is broken.

It currently works by renaming every VM to include the same serial number (first one on the list), instead of using the serial number associated with the correct VM.

I'd appreciate any help to solve this issue.

I've got this code so far: https://pastebin.com/XyDcAqvx

```
$VMPrefix = "xtest"
$VMs = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\virtualization\v2 -class Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData | `
Where-Object {$_.elementname -like "*$VMPrefix*"} | `
select elementname, BIOSSerialNumber

foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
Rename-VM $VM.elementname -NewName ($VMPrefix + $VM.BiosSerialNumber.substring(0,4))
}
```

Selecting for elementname and S/N results in:

```
elementname BIOSSerialNumber                
----------- ----------------                
xtest7749 7749-2038-3241-8243-8506-8264-01
xtest7749 7296-0806-3378-0069-7005-3271-32
xtest7749 1690-8323-7476-5112-2317-7980-11
```

It's supposed to end up looking like this:

```
elementname BIOSSerialNumber                
----------- ----------------                
xtest7749 7749-2038-3241-8243-8506-8264-01
xtest7296 7296-0806-3378-0069-7005-3271-32
xtest1690 1690-8323-7476-5112-2317-7980-11
```

Comment: This code as you have it works fine for me.  Are you running as an administrator?  Also, if you're running into this this issue with the script when running from the PowerShell ISE, try to close and reopen it, as the ISE has a long variable lifespan which might throw off your results. One suggestion, add a filter of 'Where BIOSSerialNumber.GetType().Name eq GUID'' to omit the Quick Connect VM templates.

Comment: It seems I was lacking some permissions on the account I was working on, as it worked as intended on a different admin account. Thanks for the help.